# Need help entering a variable Countblank

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

Long story short: Incoming and outgoing personnel are constantly changing. For the most part everyone is assigned to a department but not all have an assigned service, so they have a blank cell. I would like to count how many personnel have blank service cells. I tried `=COUNTBLANK` but I would like the range to be variable based on the total departments column. I tried to enter a pic but says I need rep points.

So Example:

```
-Departments            --Service

 1. Surgery             --A Co 
 2. Surgery             --B Co Nursing  
 3. Anes Nsg            --DCI Research            
 4. Surgery             --"blank cell" 
 5. Surgery             --B Co 
 6. Nursing             --Anes Nsg 
 7. DCI                 --Research 
 8. Surgery             --"blank cell" 
 9. Surgery             --"blank cell"
 10. and so on...
 11. and so on till about 630 cells
```

I would like to find out the total number of blank cells in the data (Service). Only thing is I tried with `=COUNTBLANK(B2:B630)` which is fine for this months audit but personnel are always being added or deleted so B630 end of range this month and possibly B650 the next. I would like it to be based off the total number on the first column (Departments) since people will always have to be placed into a department, that way it updates automatically without my finding the end of the range.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question seems to lack relevant information. Please update with examples of what your spreadsheets look like etc. I have voted to close this question due to lack of information, but I will happily remove that vote if the question is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you have a list similar to this one:

```
A         B
Employee  Department
Empl. 1   Dep 1
Empl. 2   Dep 1
Empl. 3   
Empl. 4   Dep 1
Empl. 5   Dep 2
Empl. 6   
Empl. 7   Dep 2
```

and you need to count of employees without a department - but as you don't know how many rows are populated, you cannot simply use `=COUNTBLANK(B2:B8)`, as B8 might be different...

If this is the case, you can use this formula:

```
=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET($B$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1,1))
```

This will count the number of employees - and the resize the department column to be counted using the `OFFSET` function.

Comment: great! in this case, please mark it as the answer (by clicking on the small checkmark left of the answer). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Peter for your assistance.